# Login with Facebook Phonegap Plugin Issue

Tags: phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, facebook-login

```
/* global FB */
"use strict";

/*
 * @author Ally Ogilvie
 * @copyright Wizcorp Inc. [ Incorporated Wizards ] 2014
 * @file - facebookConnectPlugin.js
 * @about - JavaScript interface for PhoneGap bridge to Facebook Connect SDK
 *
 *
 */

if (!window.cordova) {
// This should override the existing facebookConnectPlugin object created from cordova_plugins.js
    var facebookConnectPlugin = {

    getLoginStatus: function (s, f) {
        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
                s(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    showDialog: function (options, s, f) {

        if (!options.name) {
            options.name = "";
        }
        if (!options.message) {
            options.message = "";
        }
        if (!options.caption) {
            options.caption = "";
        }
        if (!options.description) {
            options.description = "";
        }
        if (!options.href) {
            options.href = "";
        }
        if (!options.picture) {
            options.picture = "";
        }

        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.ui({
                method: options.method,
                message: options.message,
                name: options.name,
                caption: options.caption,
                description: (
                    options.description
                ),
                href: options.href,
                picture: options.picture
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response && (response.request || !response.error_code)) {
                    s(response);
                } else {
                    f(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },
    // Attach this to a UI element, this requires user interaction.
    login: function (permissions, s, f) {
        // JS SDK takes an object here but the native SDKs use array.
        var permissionObj = {};
        if (permissions && permissions.length > 0) {
            permissionObj.scope = permissions.toString();
        }

        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                s(response);
            } else {
                f(response.status);
            }
        }, permissionObj);
    },

    getAccessToken: function (s, f) {
        var response = FB.getAccessToken();
        if (!response) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error("NO_TOKEN");
            } else {
                f("NO_TOKEN");
            }
        } else {
            s(response);
        }
    },

    logEvent: function (eventName, params, valueToSum, s, f) {
        // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
        s();
    },

    logPurchase: function (value, currency, s, f) {
        // AppEvents are not avaliable in JS.
        s();
    },

    logout: function (s, f) {
        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.logout( function (response) {
                s(response);
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    api: function (graphPath, permissions, s, f) {
        // JS API does not take additional permissions

        // Try will catch errors when SDK has not been init
        try {
            FB.api(graphPath, function (response) {
                if (response.error) {
                    f(response);
                } else {
                    s(response);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            if (!f) {
                console.error(error.message);
            } else {
                f(error.message);
            }
        }
    },

    // Browser wrapper API ONLY
    browserInit: function (appId, version) {
        if (!version) {
            version = "v2.0";
        }
        FB.init({
            appId      : appId,
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : version
        })
    }
};

// Bake in the JS SDK
(function () {
    if (!window.FB) {
        console.log("launching FB SDK");
        var e = document.createElement('script');
        e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
        e.async = true;
        document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }
}());

}
```

I'm having error of FB not Defined when I try login with facebook in my code and gives error in above js file that FB is not Defined.